# How to convert symbolic expression to function handle for optimization [Matlab]?

Tags: matlab, function

```
syms a12 a13
x=sym('x',[1,2]);
fun=a12+a13
fun=subs(fun,[a12 a13],[x(1) x(2)])
%fun=matlabFunction(fun)
fun = @(x) fun
```

I am pursuing the method to substitute all the symbols in a symbol expression by a variables vector and convert the symbol expression into a function @(x), so that I can use this function for optimization.

Comment: I have tried “matlabFunction”, but it seems regard (x1, x2) as the variables instead of vector x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right path when choosing to employ [matlabfunction](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html). However, you probably missed out one of its optional parameters, signally `Vars`;

> Order of input variables or vectors in a generated MATLAB function,
>   specified as a character vector, a vector of symbolic variables, or a
>   one-dimensional cell array of character vectors, symbolic variables,
>   or vectors of symbolic variables.
>
> The number of specified input variables must equal or exceed the
>   number of free variables in f. Do not use the same names for the input
>   variables specified by Vars and the output variables specified by
>   Outputs.
>
> By default, when you convert symbolic expressions, the order is
>   alphabetical. When you convert symbolic functions, their input
>   arguments appear in front of other variables, and all other variables
>   are sorted alphabetically.
>
> See [Specify Input Arguments for Generated Function](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html#mw_a86df32c-58e6-49e8-b99c-7174810bdfec)

```
syms a12 a13;
x = sym('x',[1,2]);
fun = a12 + a13;
fun=subs(fun,[a12 a13],[x(1) x(2)]);
g = matlabFunction(fun,'Vars',{x})

g =   
    function_handle with value:
      @(in1)in1(:,1)+in1(:,2)
```

For the sake of testing if it works:

```
k = [1 2];
g(k) % Output: 3
```